# Dell Streak 7 stuck on 2.2.2 ("read only" bug?)

Tags: 2.2-froyo, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery

I ordered two DS7s.  One came with 3.x and one came with 2.2.2 and is pretty adamant about there not being an update available.  So I decided to do it myself.  I've got Clockwork Mod Recovery 3.0.2.0 (also tried many other versions) and I've tried numerous different ROMs.  I got two to "work".  They went through the motions, said formatting, copying, etc.  Looked like it worked perfectly.  When I reboot, it's still 2.2.2 with all my previous settings.  I've done this multiple times.  It is rooted.  I've also done numerous factory resets before and after flashing the "working" ROMs.

Suggestions?

Comment: Strange that this is happening despite you having CWM persist through it.  Does `/system/etc/install-recovery.sh` exist on your device?